# Using checkbox in echo as table

Tags: php

I have a code where I echo a table:

```
<?php


// connect to the database
include('core/base.php');

// get results from database
$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM uitslag ORDER BY ID ASC") 
    or die(((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));  

// display data in table


echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Nummer</th><th>Naam</th><th>Telefoon</th><th>Binnen</th> <th>Adres</th> <th>Postcode</th> <th>Wijk</th></tr>";

// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {

    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>' . $row['ID'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Naam'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Telefoon'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Binnen'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Adres'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Postcode'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['Wijk'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['ID'] . '">Aanpassen</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>"; 
} 

// close table>
echo "</table>";
```

?>

The row 'Telefoon' either echos 1 or 0. How can I echo a checkbox which is checked when 1 instead of echoing the actual number?

Comment: there's no "checkbox" here; unless it's a "show me how to do this" type of question.

Comment: Your code is not clear. Please provide more.

Comment: echo '<td>' . (isset($row['Telefoon']) ? "<input ..." : "" ) . '</td>';

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, it is a show me how to do this type of question. I tried the search but I can't find out how to echo a checked checkbox.

Comment: Ternary operator's the best to use for stuff like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define input element of type checkbox.Like this.

```
$telefoon = ($row['Telefoon']==1)?'checked':'';
echo '<td>' . $row['ID'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['Naam'] . '</td>';
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' $telefoon></td>";
echo '<td>' . $row['Binnen'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['Adres'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['Postcode'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['Wijk'] . '</td>';
```

Comment: I tried this but then the checkbox stays unchecked even if the value is 1

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
     if($row['Telefoon']==1){
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' checked></td>";
     }
     else {
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' ></td>";
     }
?>
```